# C++: Remotely hibernate a PC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shutdown

How can I hibernate a Windows machine that runs Windows 7 or 8 over my LAN from another PC?
Is there a WinAPI function for that? Or do I have to send special magic packets or something like this?
All I know is that PsShutdown.exe is able to do it (allegedly. I haven't tried it).

I don't want to use third party libraries and I also don't want to run a service on the computer that is supposed to get hibernated. I want to use the existing mechanism.

I'd also like to know if I need to change specific settings on the target computer.
I'm not sure if that's important, but `shutdown /s /m \\ComputerName` did not work on my target PC.

Answer (score 0):

The TechNet document [**Restart or Shut Down a Remote Computer and Document the Reason**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416.aspx) describes the requirements to use the `shutdown.exe` command against a remote computer.

1. In order to use this feature, the [Remote Registry service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754820.aspx) must be enabled on the remote computer.
2. Access to the Remote Registry or membership in the **Administrators** group on the remote computer is the minimum required to complete this procedure

Comment: You misunderstood two things. First of all, I want to use an API function, COM or similar and secondly I want to hibernate my target PC, not shutting it down or restarting it. The problem with shutdown.exe is, that it is a dedicated exe which would mean insanely bad performance, especially when ran repeatedly and also very little control and no hibernate for remote PCs.

Comment: The [`InitiateShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872(v=vs.85).aspx) API function looks like the API `shutdown.exe` is based around as it has many of the same flags. I think you'll find that the requirements listed above hold whether you're using the API directly or via `shutdown.exe` (and I don't really understand your "insanely bad performance" comment - how frequently are you going to be doing this anyway?).

Comment: It may not be possible to remotely hibernate using the standard API which is presumably why `shutdown.exe` doesn't provide the option. `PsShutdown` seems to work by copying a program to the remote machine via it's admin share, at least that's what's described in the Windows IT Pro article linked from the `PsShutdown` page.

Comment: Well, for now I would just need to run shutdown.exe once, but I would still consider it bad programming style and it is just not what I am looking for. How could I reproduce this "copying a program to the remote machine via it's admin share" and how would I then tell the machine to run this program?

Comment: I don't know off-hand, maybe that Windows IT Pro article explains how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the only way to remotely hibernate a machine is to use the same method that `psshutdown` does: copy an executable to the remote machine and install it as a system service.

The [OpenSCManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API allows you to specify a target computer, and you can use the handle it returns to call CreateService and then StartService.  The service can delete itself once it has done its work.